# How to configure Orleans DI container to resolve a service with same instance per grain object graph?

Tags: dependency-injection, orleans

I'm using Microsoft Orleans, and I have a grain called ConsumerGrain that is associated with an Azure subscription by the subscription's id. The grain is injected with several application services in order to comply with SOLID principles. Some application services require the subscription's id. Instead of passing around the subscription id on every method call, I'd like to have an ISubscriptionContext object injected to every application service that requires the current subscription id, and I'd like the service instance to be created once per grain's object graph, so it can't be Transient not Singleton lifestyles. Can Scoped lifestyle be used here?

Comment: Interesting question. I did not saw any major IoC libs integration packages for Orleans. Generally IoC containers have two ways of solving such case: manually BeginLifetimeScope like in Autofac, or associating scope with the object in graph like LifeStyle.BoundTo in Castle.Winsdor, PerOwned in Autofac.

Comment: In Unity DI there is something like a "per resolve lifetime manager". Since Orleans uses ASP.NET Core DI which is a so-called [conforming container](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/06/whats-wrong-with-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/) there is no such type of dependency resolution. One solution could be to open a scope for each grain instance and register the dependencies as scoped singletons. But this scope ought to be opened by the Orleans infrastructure whenever a grain is instantiated. As a consequence the scope ought to be closed when a grain is deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

Orleans uses the `IServiceProvider` returned by the Silo `Startup` class for grains resolving only. This means the application can return a composite IServiceProvider with the following logic in the `Startup` class:

1. Build an `IServiceProvider` based on the `IServiceCollection` provided by Orleans, used to resolve Orleans internal grains.
2. Build an `IServiceProvider` for application's grains & services, let's say using SimpleInjector with per-object-graph lifestyle.
3. Return an `IServiceProvider` that first tries to resolve using the Orleans based `IServiceProvider`, and if fails resolve using the application based `IServiceProvider`.

the `Startup` class just needs to have a method in it matching this signature:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     return services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

is this snippet `BuildServiceProvider()` is supplied by Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Answer (score 0):

There is a more detailed explanation at:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1099750/How-to-implement-DI-support-in-your-Orleans-Silo

It's important to know that you have to set the Startup Class in the configuration file of orleans.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrleansConfiguration xmlns="urn:orleans">
  <Globals>
    <SeedNode Address="localhost" Port="10000" />
  </Globals>
  <Defaults>
    <Startup Type="Grains.Startup, Grains" /><!--important-->
    <Networking Address="localhost" Port="10000" />
    <ProxyingGateway Address="localhost" Port="30000" />
  </Defaults>
</OrleansConfiguration>
```